# Model property does much the value of the input it's bound within razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm building a web app using razor pages.
I have two models `Dossier` and `Log` . I generated crud razor pages for `Dossier` automatically using scaffolding.

When submitting the form bound with Log Model, it create a Log Model entity with `NumeroDeDossier = 1`, Even though I have bound Log.NumeroDeDossier with a hidden input in my form with a value of `Dossier.NumeroDeDossier`.

The Log Model:

```
public class Log
{
    public int LogID { get; set; }
    public int NumeroDeDossier { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Agent")]
    public int AgentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateDeSortie { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateDeRetour { get; set; }

    public Log()
    {
        DateDeSortie = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

The Dossier Model:

```
public class Dossier
{
    [Key]
    public int NumeroDeDossier { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Agent")]
    public int AgentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Placard")]
    public string PlacardID { get; set; }
    public int Tiroir { get; set; }
    public bool ExFlag { get; set; }

    public Dossier()
    {
        ExFlag = true;
    }

}
```

My Dossier `Index.cshtml` I Display a list of Dossiers. And has a button if clicked it displays a bootstrap modal, with a form input.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Dossier) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumeroDeDossier)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgentID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlacardID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tiroir)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if(item.ExFlag)
            {
                <div class="situation in"></div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="situation out"></div>
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.NumeroDeDossier">تعديل</a> |
            <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.NumeroDeDossier">تفاصيل</a> |
            <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.NumeroDeDossier">حذف</a> |
            // here is the modal trigger
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeShoes" class="borrow">استعارة</a>
        </td>

        <div class="form-group" style="display:none">
            // Added the input outside of the model to have an input for every item.
            //vaue of the input is Numero de Dossier (When i change it with a const ("11" for exemple) ut works)
            <input form="myform" asp-for="Log.NumeroDeDossier" class="form-control" value="@item.NumeroDeDossier"/> 
            <span asp-validation-for="Log.NumeroDeDossier" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <div class="modal fade" id="largeShoes" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabelLarge" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabelLarge">رجاء أدخل رقم تأجير المستعير</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="myform" method="POST">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">رقم التأجير @item.NumeroDeDossier </label>
                            <input asp-for="Log.AgentID" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Log.AgentID" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="إضافة" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

the form is linked to Index.cshtml.cs which create a Log Object and add it to the database `ONPOST`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Log.Add(Log);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a hidden form field instead of a text field that is wrapped in an element with `display: none`. The `display: none` will prevent the element from being rendered, so the text field is also never rendered. And a text field that isn’t rendered is also not included in the form data when the form is submitted.

So because the property is an `int` but no data is being sent, the default value for an `int` is being used when the object is being created. And the default value for `int` is 0.

So instead, use a hidden form field with a constant value:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Log.NumeroDeDossier" value="@item.NumeroDeDossier" />
```

Just put that inside your `<form>` tag. Because it has `type="hidden"`, it will not be rendered but the value will still be sent as part of the form request.

Comment: I removed `display:none` and replaced it with `type:hidden` and still have the same problem.
When I put `Item.NumeroDeDossier` inside the modal, I always get the value 1. Maybe it's the modal who is preventing it from getting the value it should have.